# android junit test case for if statement

Tags: android, junit

Hii i am new to junit test for android so my question is i have 6 `EditText` fields and one `Button` by pressing the `Button` it will check weather the field length of `EditText` fields are zero,if they are zero then it will show a `Toast` and otherwise it will go to another `Activity` so here is the my code

```
Button.OnClickListener okListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(text1.getText().toString().length()==0 || text2.getText().toString().length()==0||text3.getText().toString().length()==0||   text4.getText().toString().length()==0||text5.getText().toString().length()==0||    text6.getText().toString().length()==0||txt7.getText().toString().length()==0||txt8.getText().toString().length()==0){
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(ActivityOne.this,
                        "Field shouldn't left blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        msg.show();
}
```

i got to know how to write the Testcases for `if` `statement`  anybody has idea about how write Testcases for `Toast`. using **`Robotium`** also not a issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
// JUnit class
Button.OnClickListener okListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                assertTrue(text1.getText().toString().isEmpty() || 
                            text2.getText().toString().isEmpty()||
                            text3.getText().toString().isEmpty()||
                            text4.getText().toString().isEmpty()||
                            text5.getText().toString().isEmpty()|| 
                            text6.getText().toString().isEmpty()||
                            txt7.getText().toString().isEmpty()||
                            txt8.getText().toString().isEmpty());
    }

public void testButtons() {
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(okListener);
    okListener.onClick(yourButton);
}
```

PS1: use `String.isEmpty()` instead of `String.length() == 0`.

PS2: I suggest you use an array/List for your `EditText` instead. Having one field for each is really a bad way of doing it. What happens if you add/remove one `EditText`? You would need to scan all your code to find that `EditText` and remove it. Using an array/List you only need to update the array/List.

Comment: I cannot add JUnit to your code because I don't have your code. What is exactly what you didn't get?

Comment: this is not wt i mean where is ur assertions  why ur using listButtons i have only one button in my application..

Comment: Ok I read wrong. If you want assertions you need to set up a different listener for your button in your JUnit test.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working  now in want to write test case for Toast how to do it do u have any idea.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"test case for Toast"*. I suggest you make a new question explaining it in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests not suitable to test GUI.

Fro this purposes try to use for example [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/).

Comment: Not that much you button and listener are a the problems ( [ActivityUnitTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html) would sort this out) but it seems really tricky with your Toast. Use Robotium. Robotium works.

Comment: For testing logic (pressing buttons, filling view etc) unit tests are ok, but the main trouble in this question is GUI test (toast =) ) - and in this case unit tests are useless

Comment: leave the Toast part just tell me how to check the if condition .thanks alot.

Comment: As Aurdrius said you can use ActivityUnitTestCase, you can find an example here: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-testing-example-helloworld-with-activityunittestcase/  or more detailed here: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes i finally find out the junit TestCase for Toast and its very simple by using **Robotium** here the code will like this

```
 Solo solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    // Now do whatever you need to do to trigger your dialog.

    // Let's assume a properly lame dialog title.
    assertTrue("Could not find the dialog!", solo.searchText("MY Dialog Title"));
```